# Datatables not loading with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.1

I am using datatables within Laravel 5.1 and am getting the error alert;

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

This is along with the below showing in the console;

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.website.co.uk/api/datatable.json?_=1451163779367
```

I cannot seem to find the issue, is it due to using laravel and the system looking for /api/ as a route?

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue ?

Comment: explain the model of the failing table, how do you retrieve it and send it to data table, also how did you use your data table. a bare - without stacktrace or such - error message won't do any good to understand the real problem.